# Getting 'Subquery returns more than 1 row' when updating a row - MariaDB

Tags: mysql, eloquent, mariadb

I got an error

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more
> than 1 row (SQL: update `submissions` set `status` = 2, `updated_at` =
> '2020-11-11 09:02:27' where `id` = 85213835).

I'm using Eloquent ORM 5.7 and the the code is looks like this

```
$builder->update([
        'status' => $request->getParam('new_status'),
        'rejection_message' => $request->getParam('rejection_message') ? $request->getParam('rejection_message') : ""
    ]);
```

Previously the code was running well and just got this error recently.

Comment: missing quotes around 2020-11-11 09:02:27 ?

Comment: it;s the message from debugger, but if I add quotes around the timestamp and run the query it will get the error 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Comment: Check table and indices integrity...

Comment: 'id' is primary key of table and have is_unique index

Comment: Is a `TRIGGER` involved?

Comment: Yes there’s a trigger involved